# How to connect to local Database in Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm absolute beginner to ORACLE ,so I installed SQL developer to start practising query then I installed Oracle Database, after which I got the following screen

[image: Oracle DB Installation screen]

Then when I tried to create new connection with the following credentials

```
>Connection name: HR_DB
>Username :HR
>Password :HR
>Hostname :localhost
>port     :1521
>sid      :orcl
```

Now I get the following error

> Status: Failure -Test Failed:ORA-01017 invalid username/password; logon denied

Please help me to get connected to local Database account ,I have absolutely no idea what's happening.

Comment: _invalid username/password;_ - what's unclear about that message exactly?

Comment: so how do I login,like how to create new user credentials or is there a default username and password available?

Comment: You specified passwords when you created the database. Please search for and read the docs on user management, this is all documented.

Comment: @Yuvi When installing Oracle DB you need to specify password for system schema. Use that password to log in as user `system` and alter the password of HR schema and re-connect. But AFAIK default password for HR schema is HR. So I'm not sure what's going wrong in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an Oracle installation in front of me right now, so I can't remember if you'll get this error if the account is locked or not.  But the HR user is locked by default if I remember correctly. [Docs on unlocking HR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_connecting.htm#TDDDG12500)

Also, if you haven't created the HR schema, yet, you'll need to do that.  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/installation.htm#COMSC001) are the docs for that.

Alternatively, if you created it with the wrong password, or changed the password, you'll have to login as a dba user `ALTER USER hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK IDENTIFIED BY Password;`

Comment: I get it I didn't unlock account's and set password in Password management window during installation. Is  there any way to open that window now? this query ALTER USER hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK IDENTIFIED BY Password; didn't work becoz illegal zero length identifier error becoz password wasn't set.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "open that window."  But if you mean log in as a system user and fix the password, then yes.  The link provided describes how to do that and more.

Comment: I had this error sql developer status failure test failed ora -28000 the account is locked. And this works for me, thanks.